# What does find_package(Name) do besides calling FindName.cmake?

Tags: cmake

According to the documentation [`find_package()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) has two modes. My question focuses on the "Module" mode.

> The command has two modes by which it searches for packages: “Module” mode and “Config” mode. Module mode is available when the command is invoked with the above reduced signature. CMake searches for a file called Find.cmake in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH followed by the CMake installation. If the file is found, it is read and processed by CMake.

Is there anything else than finding the find script and executing it? If so, why would I use `find_package(Name)` and not just call `include(FindName.cmake)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When script is executed, `find_package` also sets some variables, according to arguments it is called with. See documentation page you refer:

> When loading a find module or package configuration file `find_package` defines variables to provide information about the call arguments (and restores their original state before returning):

Comment: For example, if I would just include `FindName.cmake`, would shorthands like `find_package_handle_standard_args()` still work?

Comment: `find_package_handle_standard_args`, as name states, uses variables, provided with `find_package()`, so it wouldn't work with direct including file. You may `include(name/find.cmake)` inside `FindName.cmake`, and use later via `find_package(name)`.